# Can't change or remove grey background with material-ui

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui

I have a simple React app that uses material-ui. No matter what I try, I cannot remove a grey background from a section of an app.

Tried:

```
body {
  background-color: #ffffff !important; 
}

* {
   background-color: #ffffff !important; 
}
```

No matter what I do, I cannot make the main container white. It always goes grey. I've searched my app and all css for this background-color and cannot find it...I cannot determine what is causing this grey background.

[image: fucked up background-color]
[image: closer]

Answer (score 0):

Ugh!

Double check your header doesn't have a box-shadow on it! This will cause the grey below...

Leaving this question as maybe it can help someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Ensure that your element does not have any class. If it does try removing it or check the style of the class and whether it has a backgroundColor parameter.